# Create indexes on initdb script

Tags: mongodb, docker, initialization

I have a custom docker image from mongo:4.2-6-bionic with two initdb scripts:

- /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-database-seed.sh
- /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-create-indexes.sh

When the image is created, the 1-database-seed.sh file is executed correctly. But, 2-create-indexes.sh is not executed.

If i execute manually 2-create-indexes.sh, inside the container, the script runs correctly. The script content is:

```
#!/bin/bash

mongo renaper --eval "db.names_indexed.createIndex({'fullname': 1})";
mongo renaper --eval "db.names_indexed.createIndex({'year': 1})";
mongo renaper --eval "db.names_indexed.createIndex({'fullname': 1,'year': 1})";
mongo renaper --eval "db.names_indexed.createIndex({'fullname': 'text'})";
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What does "doesn't" mean?

Comment: @Oleg 2-create-indexes.sh is not executed.

Comment: What is different between the two scripts?

Comment: @Oleg the first script imports some json files, the second create some indexes. I put all in one and works fine.

Comment: What if you put all into the other one?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I put all the tasks in a single file and it worked correctly.